# SWIG - Exporting C++ classes to Lua as globals

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I am using SWIG 3.0 to make the C++ classes in my application (a game engine) available to Lua. The problem is that, instead of making the classes available as global symbols in my application, they are put inside a global table with the name of the module. For example, I have to use my Color class like this:

```
local myColor = module.Color.red()
```

But what I want is this:

```
local myColor = Color.red()
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious here, but I have not found any explanation on how to do this on the SWIG documentation nor here.